# [macOS]how to copy file to /Library in Mac

Tags: objective-c, macos

I want to copy my an Audio Driver to /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/, but an error occurred.

> open on /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/MyAudio.driver.tgz: Permission denied

here is my code:

```objectivec
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        // insert code here...
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:@"/Users/duoduo/root/MyAudio.driver.tgz" toPath:@"/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/MyAudio.driver.tgz" error:NULL];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

how to ask for permission before copy file to /Library?
Thanks!

Comment: `/Library` belongs to the system. You have no write permission, not even in a non-sandboxed environment. A possible workaround is to run an AppleScript which copies the file `with administrator privileges`. But if the app is sandboxed, there is no (easy) way,

Comment: Thank you @vadian .You said that there is no (easy) way. But I do have an application that can copy folder to /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/. Unfortunately, I don't have their source code.

Comment: Basically it is impossible to write into `/Library` without entering an admin password. As I said the easy way – in a non-sandboxed app – is an AppleScript, the hard way – in a sandboxed app – is a privileged helper, an XPC service.

Comment: Hi @vadian ,I never learn how to write an AppleScript. Could you please tell me how to write into /Library through an AppleScript? Thank you.

Comment: It's actually one line, a shell script `do shell script "/bin/cp /Users/duoduo/root/MyAudio.driver.tgz /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/MyAudio.driver.tgz" with administrator privileges`. Copy the line in Script Editor and run it. You can save it as application to be able to run it without an AppleScript runner application.